# DirectX11 Get Swapchain of a Device

Tags: c++, device, directx-11

I need the swapchain of a program so I can access it's backbuffer, but I can only get the device. Is there a way to get the swapchain from a device?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?  The swap chain is created at the same time as the device in a call to D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain

Comment: No I don't. I am trying to get access to the swapchain from another program, and I have the device, but cant find a path to the swapchain. Apparently nobody ever thought somebody would need that.

Comment: How did you get the device anyway?

Comment: It(unity) provides it via api. Sadly not the device chain.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is copy the backbuffer (or share or whatever is fastest) into my own and render that onto my own window (create a copy of the unity's render output).

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. An application could have any number of Swap Chains, one per pane on a UI, one per monitor, etc. How would you know which of the many swap chains that have been created is the one you want?